# Get return value from a method in ionic template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I was trying to get the return value from a method in ionic template.
what I know and tried is the following :-

```html
<button (click) = "getReturn(parameter)">btn</button>
```

```
getReturn(para)
{
   return para*2;
}
```

This is just an example of what I tried , but I am aware how to fetch the return value.

Comment: What do you need to do?

Comment: I need to get the return value, based on which I will change the UI

Comment: If you want to change the UI based on that than you will probably need to store it in a component variable

Comment: But what shall I need to do , when the html buttons are inside a for loop and I need to change only the button which the user clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the return element of the method should be reflected in the UI, it will be best to set it to an attribute of the component like below

```
<button (click) = "setReturn(parameter)">btn</button>


setReturn(para)
{
   this.attribute = para*2;
}
```

then use `attribute` in the html

If the button click is part of a loop, then you would need to change the element at index i of the loop

```
<button *ngFor="let parameter of parameters; let i= index" (click) = "setReturn(parameter, i)">btn</button>

setReturn(para, index)
{
   this.parameters[i] = para*2;
}
```

Comment: This seems lot convincing, sorry if I was not clear with my problem statement, my problem statement is that I am building a chat app in which the users are able to record audio and send , those things the working fine , the problems comes when the user tries to play the audio, I am not able to figure out how to change only the button selected from play to pause , moreover how to get the return using which  I can signify the audio track is finished. 
PS : noob

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you are trying to do this:

```
<button (click)="getReturn(parameter)">btn</button>
```

TS

```
para = 1; //or 0 whatever you need 

getReturn(para)
{
   this.para = para*2
}
```

I do not think returning value in `click()` is going to help somewhere. with this now you can use value of `para` wherever you want in the component UI